# Jquery determines that when the uploaded image is empty, let its parent node hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How does jquery determine when the uploaded image is empty, let its parent node hide? I have written the code, but it doesn't work! Can you give me some suggestions, or the corresponding examples? Thank you very much!

```
<p id="new_zs">hello! <img src="'+ addressUrl+list.ccieimg+'" alt=""></p>
<script>
  $(function() {
    if ($('#new_zs img').attr('src')) {         
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }       
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because the scope of `this`, in the location you're running the jQuery code, will be the `window`, not the `#new_zs img` element.

To fix this you will need to specifically target the `#new_zs` element. Also note that `show()` is redundant, as that's the default state anyway, so the logic can be simplified to just:

```js
$(function() {
  if (!$('#new_zs img').attr('src'))
    $('#new_zs').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="new_zs">hello! <img src="" alt=""></p>
```

Note that this is assuming that you're outputting an empty string in to the `src` attribute of the HTML. If that's not the case you will need to change your `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks very much! But I've changed it, but there's no change in the front end! I don't know what's the reason?

Comment: I've added the code in the answer to a snippet so you can see it working. If this isn't working for you then we need to see the actual HTML output to the page. Could you please edit that in to the question

Comment: Thanks! I'm try it !

Answer (score 1):

Image elements can trigger an `error` event and a `load` event that you can use to see if an image is correctly loaded.

- The `error` event happens when the location in the src event does not
  return a valid image or does not return at all.
- The `load` event happens when the image is successfully loaded.

I made an example of these functions for you below.

---

You can use the error handler to check if something went wrong with the image. This also works if the url is incorrect. The only downside is that it does not trigger an error when no src attribute is defined as you can see in the below snippet.

```js
$('.img').on('error', function() {
  console.log('incorrect source:' + $(this).attr('id'));
  $(this).parent('p').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="new_zs1">hello1!<img class="img" id="img1" src="" /></p>
<p id="new_zs2">hello2!<img class="img" id="img2" src="http://www.incorrectdomain.stupid/hahah.png" /></p>
<p id="new_zs3">hello3!<img class="img" id="img3" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></p>
<p id="new_zs4">hello4!<img class="img" id="img4"/></p>
```

---

Alternatively you can hide all images at first and show images only if the image is loaded successful. This works for images without a `src` element too.

```js
$('.img').parent('p').hide();

$('.img').on('load', function(){
  console.log('Correct image: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
  $(this).parent('p').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="new_zs1">hello1!<img class="img" id="img1" src="" /></p>
<p id="new_zs2">hello2!<img class="img" id="img2" src="http://www.incorrectdomain.stupid/hahah.png" /></p>
<p id="new_zs3">hello3!<img class="img" id="img3" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></p>
<p id="new_zs4">hello4!<img class="img" id="img4"/></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm try it!

Comment: @nextion Updated the code to use jQuery `on()` instead.

Comment: @nextion Another option come to my mind which is probably the best solution. See my second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This will do multiple images

```js
$('img[src=""]').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>image show <img src="/" alt=""></p>
<p>image Hide <img src="" alt=""></p>
<p>image show <img src="/" alt=""></p>
<p>image Hide <img src="" alt=""></p>
```

For your single image

```
$('#new_zs img[src=""]').parent().hide();
```

Comment: thank you very much. How to design a single upload image?

Comment: `$('img').each()` is not needed here. In fact it makes things worse. When having 4 images without a `src` value. it will call `hide()` 4 times for each image.

Comment: @MarkBaijens can you explain to me why it would call .hide() 4 times per img please?

Comment: @MarkBaijens ignore that last comment i have just seen the logic, you are correct thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @Jim-miraidev It's better, but still don't need the `each()` function.`$('img[src=""]').parent().hide();` is enough. Jquery will execute the code on all elements of your selection.